# jrxml to jasper using gradle

Tags: gradle, ant, jasper-reports

while trying to compile jrxml using ant task inside gradle, jasper file is not getting generated. below errors are seen in gradle console. please provide pointers on this. Below are the errors gradle build file with ant task.

Note: all the required jasper and other dependency jars are placed under libs directory

**ERRORS:**

```
2020-10-28T15:09:51.520+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc] ERROR: Could not compile report [/builds/DFSDocker.Admin/rhel_dec_release/compileux/customjrxml/src/main/jasperreports/UBBDFail.jrxml]. Exception: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
2020-10-28T15:09:51.520+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
2020-10-28T15:09:51.520+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc] calculator_UBBDFail_1603897790979_43679: 24: unable to resolve class net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.GroovyEvaluator 
2020-10-28T15:09:51.520+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc]  @ line 24, column 1.
2020-10-28T15:09:51.520+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc] calculator_UBBDFail_1603897790979_43679: 34: unable to resolve class JRFillParameter 
2020-10-28T15:09:51.520+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc]  @ line 34, column 5.
2020-10-28T15:09:51.520+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc] calculator_UBBDFail_1603897790979_43679: 35: unable to resolve class JRFillParameter 
2020-10-28T15:09:51.520+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc]  @ line 35, column 5.
2020-10-28T15:09:51.520+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc] calculator_UBBDFail_1603897790979_43679: 36: unable to resolve class JRFillParameter 
2020-10-28T15:09:51.520+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc]  @ line 36, column 5.
2020-10-28T15:09:51.521+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc] calculator_UBBDFail_1603897790979_43679: 37: unable to resolve class JRFillParameter 
2020-10-28T15:09:51.521+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc]  @ line 37, column 5.
2020-10-28T15:09:51.521+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc] calculator_UBBDFail_1603897790979_43679: 38: unable to resolve class JRFillParameter 
2020-10-28T15:09:51.521+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc]  @ line 38, column 5.
2020-10-28T15:09:51.521+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc] calculator_UBBDFail_1603897790979_43679: 39: unable to resolve class JRFillParameter 
2020-10-28T15:09:51.521+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc]  @ line 39, column 5.
```

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
      println 'in repositories'
      dirs 'libs'
    }
}

configurations.create('jasperreports')
configurations.jasperreports {
 transitive = true
}

dependencies {
    jasperreports fileTree(dir: 'libs',include: '*.jar')
}

task compileJasperJava {
    def jasperSourceDir = file('customjrxml/src/main/jasperreports')
    def jasperTargetDir = file('customjrxml/build/classes/main/jasperreports')
    def compiler = file('customjrxml/build/classes/main/jasperreports')
    ant {
        taskdef(name: 'jrc', classname: 'net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask', classpath: configurations.jasperreports.asPath)
        jasperTargetDir.mkdirs()
        jrc(srcdir: jasperSourceDir, destdir:jasperTargetDir,compiler:'net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler') {
            include(name:'**/*.jrxml')
        }
    }
}

classes.dependsOn compileJasperJava
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding highlighted(classpath block - remove ** before using) to below build.gradle resolved the jasper generation issue.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
      println 'in repositories'
      dirs 'libs'
    }
}

configurations.create('jasperreports')
configurations.jasperreports {
 transitive = true
}

dependencies {
    jasperreports fileTree(dir: 'libs',include: '*.jar')
}

task compileJasperJava {
    def jasperSourceDir = file('customjrxml/src/main/jasperreports')
    def jasperTargetDir = file('customjrxml/build/classes/main/jasperreports')
    ant {
        taskdef(name: 'jrc', classname: 'net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask', classpath: configurations.jasperreports.asPath)
        jasperTargetDir.mkdirs()
        jrc(srcdir: jasperSourceDir, destdir:jasperTargetDir) {
            include(name:'**/*.jrxml')
            **classpath {
                pathElement(path: configurations.jasperreports.asPath)
            }**
        }
    }
}

classes.dependsOn compileJasperJava
```

Reference article: http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Classpath-issue-with-jasperreports-taskdef-td3275141.html